# Spring-core dependency version error with a Jenkins Plugin

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, dependencies, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to make a Jenkins plugin that uses [a library that requires spring-core 3.2.2 (cloudfoundry-client-lib)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-client-lib/1.0.2). I simply used the mvn command to create a skeleton plugin, then added my Maven dependency to pom.xml and a few simple code lines that uses the library. I'm not getting any problem running the skeleton plugin without my dependency.

Upon compiling with "mvn package", I'm getting a test error:

```
WARNING: Failed to scout hudson.security.PAMSecurityRealm
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
```

Looks like this is a class that appeared in spring-core 3.1.0. So I looked at the Maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:tree (default-cli) @ stackato-jenkins ---
[INFO] org.wiwiweb:cf-test-jenkins:hpi:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client-lib:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:compile
```

So Maven tells me it's using spring-core 2.5.6 because of spring-webmvc 3.2.2? This is strange because, [looking online, spring-webmvc 3.2.2 depends on spring-core 3.2.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.2.RELEASE). Looking at the verbose version of the tree, [looks like jenkins-core depends on spring-core 2.5.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/jenkins-core/1.532)... This makes me suspicious that the problem is from Jenkins.

Anyway, if it's just a version conflict, then overriding Maven's decision by explicitly saying I want spring-core 3.2.2 in my pom.xml should solve the problem, right?
I did this, then did not get a compile error. Problem solved!... not.

In runtime, after activating this plugin in Jenkins and running a build with this, as soon as the code runs into a line that uses the library I added, the Jenkins output tells me this:

```
FATAL: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap(Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;)Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap(Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;)Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;
```

UnmodifiableMultiValueMap() is a method that was added in spring-core 3.1, so this means Jenkins is still trying to run my plugin with the old version of spring-core, even though I explicitly said I wanted the newest one in my plugin's pom.xml!

So I'm stuck on this. I'm not even sure if it's a Maven or a Jenkins issue. I'll sum up the whole thing in two questions:

1. Why is Maven not compiling the plugin with a correct version of spring-core unless I explicitly tell him to? It should be able to follow dependencies without me giving it hints.
2. Why is Jenkins running my plugin with an older version of spring-core than the one it was compiled with, and how can I make it use the correct one?

Comment: Can you post the complete pom.xml?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/UGS2uRfA. Thanks for your time!

Comment: [It seems](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/mzHIU-dbAKw) this is no easy task. In that discussion, the code in   the plugin was using `org.springframework` package, whereas in your case a library your code uses, it's using `org.springframework` package. But the suggestion itself kind of says that it's not possible to simply use another version of Spring in your plugin which is different from the one Jenkins uses. Is there any chance you could build your own version of `cloudfoundry-client-lib` jar that uses Maven Shade plugin?

Comment: Can you share the complete code for your plugin? I tried a "shaded" version of `cloudfoundry-client-lib` but I haven't used Jenkins before nor I developed plugins for it so I cannot actually test if it works.

Comment: [Here is the entire source code.](https://github.com/Wiwiweb/cf-test-jenkins) That link you found is very interesting though, and I think I'll be looking into that myself too.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to test this plugin. I'm loading it in Jenkins, it says it is enabled, but when I try to create a "Build step" I'm not seeing "Push to CF" option in there. I wanted to test out the "shaded" version of that library, but I don't seem to be able to test the plugin in the first place.

Comment: That's strange, I'm seeing it correctly... However I met a problem trying to use this shaded library myself. In your link, it says to replace mentions of the library in the code with the shaded library. But I'm not using spring-core myself, the CF library is. How can I tell the CF library to use this shaded library?

Comment: That's the thing. I would try shading the CF library, meaning you need to check out the source code of the CF library, modify the pom file and get a shaded version of it. I looked at their pom and they are actually using "shading" but for other package. You need to get into their configuration for "shading" and add your own `org.springframework` package for shading. After you shade CF lib, use it in your Jenkins plugin. This is what I would try.

Comment: Let me give it another try - what version of Jenkins are you installing this plugin into? Any particular Job you create where you test this?

Comment: I've added a possible answer to your post, based on my comments above, even if I wasn't able to test my theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're picking up dependencies from the Jenkins install rather than from your plugin the solution is actual quite easy to implement. Per the [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+Structure#PluginStructure-Classloader), simply add the maven-hpi-plugin to the build in the pom.xml of your Jenkins plugin and set it to load the plugin classes first:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <pluginFirstClassLoader>true</pluginFirstClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This seemed promising and would allow me to get rid of my current clunky shading solution, however it doesn't seem to work. Here is my dependency tree: http://pastebin.com/4qSvhvgH - As you can see, it's still using spring-core:jar:2.5.6.SEC03 even though my plugin needs 3.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: @Wiwiweb This answer resolves the NoSuchMethodError encountered during run-time after deploying the hpi to Jenkins. As you mentioned in your question, you still need to add the dependencies to the pom.xml for the hpi to build. Once you add the dependencies explicitly in your pom.xml, add this build plugin configuration in the answer as well then build and deploy. The result should be that you can see the correct jar versions deployed to your plugin path on Jenkins, and now the class loader is picking those versions up so no more NoSuchMethodError during runtime.

Comment: Looks like this works great! Thanks, this will save me a lot of trouble in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try to "shade" the CF client lib using the [Maven Shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin, as it seems [Jenkins doesn't like](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/mzHIU-dbAKw) plugins that are using a different version of Spring than the one it uses internally itself.

Even if your own plugin doesn't use Spring directly, but the CF library does, I believe this still applies. The person that suggested shading in the jenkinsci-dev mailing list seems to be [involved](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hudsonci.plugins.findbugs/library/2.0.1-h-1) in Jenkins plugins development, so he might know about this more than others.

These being said, I would get the [source code for cf-client-lib](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client), I would change the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/blob/master/cloudfoundry-client-lib/pom.xml) to consider shading for `org.springframework` package, as well (because cf-client-lib already uses shading for `org.codehaus.jackson` package) and I would use this "shaded" version of cf-client-lib in the Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Though you weren't able to test your solution, you still helped me a lot. I wasn't even aware of the shaded plugin. I think I'll be able to solve this now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Attempted this with Shade and although it did shade the hpi file, the runtime conflict with the Jenkins installed Spring 2 jars still persisted.