# Different spring-core / spring-boot version in a Jenkins plugin causing trouble

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, spring-boot, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to write a Jenkins Plugin that is leveraging an existing artifact that is based on Spring Boot 1.2.6.  By default, the version of spring that I need in my plugin is Spring 4.1.7 as is used by my artifact.  However, when I look at the .hpl file that the `hpi:run` plugin generates, I noticed that it is exporting the spring-core 2.5.6 that Jenkins uses.

Based on what I read on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24066027/827480), I updated my plugin to have the following in the pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <pluginFirstClassLoader>true</pluginFirstClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Additionally, to further force the Spring versions I want/need, I added the following to my dependency management to override anything coming from the jenkins parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My goal here is to ensure that all spring dependencies declared by my plugin are the same version as required by my Boot artifact.

So far, so good.  The generated `work/plugins/vsync.hpl` file looks correct, with all the appropriate libs and versions.

However, when I run my plugin, and launch the SpringApplication, I get the following error message:

```
SEVERE: Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.fw.util.synchronize.VSync]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at com.fw.util.vsyncjenkins.VSyncPublisher.perform(VSyncPublisher.java:111)
        ...
        ...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:818)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:802)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:418)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:393)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:276)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
```

Now, I'm lost.  I checked that the jar file containing the `EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.class` (spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar) is in the hpl file and is loaded by Jenkins, so I am not sure what the error is coming from.  Plus it isn't a ClassNotFound exception, but rather a `FileNotFound` exception, which I find really strange.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated at this point as I have run out of ideas where to look or what to do.

Comment: You cannot override dependencies coming from the parent with a bom import unfortunately. `mvn dependencies:list` should confirm that. There is a fix in the upcoming Maven 3.4 release, check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5971

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll But that's just it - in my dependency:tree and my dependency:list I see all the correct libs and versions listed.  Perhaps the difference is that my are compile scope and the ones provided by jenkins are provided, but everything appears as I expect it to.